# princomp results

Tags: r

I'm doing some PCA analysis for my data. and its my first time to try this type of analysis.
I'm having a matrix of a thousand columns and few thousands of rows, and i am trying to make a smaller matrix by getting rid of correlated variables (which are the columns in my case).
everything is going great until the moment, but i am unable to do the next step.
here's an example to show my data.

```
         a1    a2    a3    a4    ....    a1000
item1    10    NA     5     3    ....
item2    0.01  0.5    NA   0.07  ....
item3    0.7   0.2    0.8  0.9   ....
                   .
                   .
                   .
```

I apply the princomp and get the following results

```
                         Comp.1     Comp.2     Comp.3     Comp.4     ...   Comp.1000
Standard deviation     24.1605431 7.31176669 5.96709553 3.56507807   ...
Proportion of Variance  0.7580933 0.06943108 0.04624186 0.01650621   ...
Cumulative Proportion   0.7580933 0.82752438 0.87376624 0.89027245   ...
                                       .
                                       .
                                       .
```

Now that i have computed everything...my question is: what command should i use to pick the uncorrelated components and paste them into a new matrix (or simply get rid of the correlated ones)?
how do i specify the range of correlation i want?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are after the `scores`.  From the help for `?princomp`, the resulting object is a list that contains an elements `scores`:

> scores
>
> if scores = TRUE, the scores of the supplied data on the
>   principal components. These are non-null only if x was supplied, and
>   if covmat was also supplied if it was a covariance list. For the
>   formula method, napredict() is applied to handle the treatment of
>   values omitted by the na.action.

Let's set up an example (based on example in `?princomp`):

```
summary(pc.cr <- princomp(USArrests, cor = TRUE))
Importance of components:
                          Comp.1    Comp.2    Comp.3     Comp.4
Standard deviation     1.5748783 0.9948694 0.5971291 0.41644938
Proportion of Variance 0.6200604 0.2474413 0.0891408 0.04335752
Cumulative Proportion  0.6200604 0.8675017 0.9566425 1.00000000
```

You can investigate the result object with `str()`:

```
str(pc.cr)
List of 7
 $ sdev    : Named num [1:4] 1.575 0.995 0.597 0.416
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Comp.1" "Comp.2" "Comp.3" "Comp.4"
 $ loadings: loadings [1:4, 1:4] -0.536 -0.583 -0.278 -0.543 0.418 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Murder" "Assault" "UrbanPop" "Rape"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Comp.1" "Comp.2" "Comp.3" "Comp.4"
 $ center  : Named num [1:4] 7.79 170.76 65.54 21.23
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Murder" "Assault" "UrbanPop" "Rape"
 $ scale   : Named num [1:4] 4.31 82.5 14.33 9.27
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Murder" "Assault" "UrbanPop" "Rape"
 $ n.obs   : int 50
 $ scores  : num [1:50, 1:4] -0.986 -1.95 -1.763 0.141 -2.524 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:50] "Alabama" "Alaska" "Arizona" "Arkansas" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Comp.1" "Comp.2" "Comp.3" "Comp.4"
 $ call    : language princomp(x = USArrests, cor = TRUE)
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "princomp"
```

Now extract the scores:

```
head(pc.cr$scores)
               Comp.1     Comp.2      Comp.3       Comp.4
Alabama    -0.9855659  1.1333924 -0.44426879  0.156267145
Alaska     -1.9501378  1.0732133  2.04000333 -0.438583440
Arizona    -1.7631635 -0.7459568  0.05478082 -0.834652924
Arkansas    0.1414203  1.1197968  0.11457369 -0.182810896
California -2.5239801 -1.5429340  0.59855680 -0.341996478
Colorado   -1.5145629 -0.9875551  1.09500699  0.001464887
```

Comment: that looks pretty nice, but i am still concerend about something here. in the example above (USArrests) i calculated the nrow(USAressts) and the result was 50, same result as nrow(pc.cr$scores). but in my default dataset, under each column, there are 11143 "items"  (i mean the Y dimension of the matrix is 11143). though i am having only 175 result under each "comp" when applying (file-after-princomp$scores). why is this happening? any clue?

Comment: oh ignore my comment, the 175 was just a representation of the data.
i did a "P <- data.frame(file-after-printcomp$scores)" and got the full list of my data. I am keeping the comment for sharing the knowledge :)